# OpenGL draw partial object in scrollable panel

Tags: user-interface, opengl, scroll, viewport, lwjgl

I am making a GUI in OpenGL (more specifically lwjgl).  I have tried hard to research different ways of doing this but I am having a hard time finding exactly what I want.  I do not want to use any external libraries (only ones built in OpenGL, even trying to stay away from using GLUT) and I would like to have it work on anything that supports OpenGL (ex. Frame Buffer Objects don't work on older graphic cards).

I am making a 3D GUI with a scrollable panel as a component.  The problem is I don't know how to draw a partial GUI component without doing a lot of calculations to only render part of it.  I am making the components out of OpenGL primitives, not textures.  I was hoping there is an easy way to do this like use multiple viewports.  I don't really even understand what viewports are.

In short: I need to have a scrollable panel as a component overlapping other GUI components (since it will be a drop down menu) and not let any of the components in my panel draw outside my panel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want to prevent drawing pixels that are outside of a rectangular region (and I think that's what you're asking), than [`glScissor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glScissor.xhtml) is exactly what you're looking for.

In lwjgl, you can find the function in [`org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11`](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL11.html#glScissor(int,int,int,int)).

Comment: You may also take advantage of GL_GLIP_PLANEs, they will allow you to clip in model space (in case your GUI coordinates don't match with viewport pixels).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scroll a larger scene within a fixed region on the screen, the most straightforward way to go is by just modifying your projection matrix for the scroll position and redrawing the scene.  If you are using gluPerspective to set up your projection matrix you'll have to convert it to a direct call to glFrustum; if you're using glOrtho it's much more straightforward.

Keep in mind that "scrolling" a perspective view has no one right way to do things - it depends on what sort of effect you want to achieve, and what particular sort of distortion you want near the edges of the overall viewport.